# Laravel 5.2 macOs Sierra phpunit test not cannot find my button

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-blade

I am trying to go to the home page and click on my button

```
 <a href="{{route('quiz.create')}}" id="createQuiz" class="crud-btn">createQuiz</a>
```

I made a test to do that

```
public function testExample()
    {
      $this->visit('/home')->click('createQuiz');
    }
```

However when I run the test with

```
phpunit --filter quizCreation "tests\quizCreation"
```

I get the error 
    ...quizWhiz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/Interac
    tsWithPages.php:464

```
InvalidArgumentException: Could not find a link with a body, name, or ID attribute of [createQuiz].
```

Comment: Do you have another element on the page with an id of `createQuiz` that is not an `a` element?

Comment: No i do not, How may I know that it's even checking the correct page? Does it matter if it has a auth middleware on it? `Route::get('/home','PagesController@getHome')->middleware('auth')->name('home');`

Comment: you need to write `#createQuiz` to tell you want to use id selector

Comment: It did not change, got `InvalidArgumentException: Could not find a link with a body, name, or ID attribute of [#createQuiz]. ... /laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/Interac

tsWithPages.php:464`